# How to enable Nfs volume service in PCF

Tags: nfs, cloud-foundry

I want to enable nfs service in PCF. Please let me know the steps.

I am not able to find Ops Manager Installation Dashboard  ?

Comment: Most of the time, you need to ask your PCF Operations Team to do this. Are you managing your PCF, or are you just using it as a developer with the cf cli?

Comment: Hi @DanielMikusa I am  using it as a developer  with cf cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a developer, there's nothing you can really do. If you do not see the [NFS service broker listed when you run `cf marketplace`](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/devguide/services/using-vol-services.html#nfs), then you need to reach out to your platform operator and ask them to enable it.

As a platform operator, you would need to [make sure the functionality is enabled & configured (this is done in Ops Manager)](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/opsguide/enable-vol-services.html#nfs-enable), then you would need to expose it to your user's orgs or mark the service as publicly available (done with the cf cli, but as an admin user, see steps 8 & 9 of the previous link).